# Avoid resizing stroke with Raphaël scaling

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

Following the top answer to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614200/draggables-and-resizables-in-svg) I was able to  make a draggable and resizable path-based shape using Raphaël.

[jsFiddle Resizable Path](http://jsfiddle.net/Josan/jnLYD/)

The one thing I can't figure out is how to avoid unequal scaling if the path has a stroke to it.  As long as the scaling is 1:1, the stroke width stays the same, but stretching the path in one direction or another thins the stroke in one direction. Is there a way to transform a path without affecting the stroke?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839936/constant-border-in-a-dynamic-svg-graphic

Answer (score 0):

Not using transformations. You could try modifying the actual path, e.g. "M10,10L20,20" would become "M10,10L40,20" (equivalent of "S2,1").

Also, have a look at [Raphael.FreeTransform](https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.FreeTransform) which handles dragging/rotating/scaling (doesn't address the stroke issue though).

Comment: Eventually there will be a couple hundred shapes, so I was hoping to avoid manipulating the actual paths. The FreeTransform is great though, thanks for the link.