# r svg-like output with lines/paths of constant size

Tags: r, svg, maps, ggplot2

Using the MWE from the `geom_polygon` example and producing a svg file.

```
ids <- factor(c("1.1", "2.1", "1.2", "2.2", "1.3", "2.3"))

values <- data.frame(
  id = ids,
  value = c(3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.15, 3.5)
)

positions <- data.frame(
  id = rep(ids, each = 4),
  x = c(2, 1, 1.1, 2.2, 1, 0, 0.3, 1.1, 2.2, 1.1, 1.2, 2.5, 1.1, 0.3,
  0.5, 1.2, 2.5, 1.2, 1.3, 2.7, 1.2, 0.5, 0.6, 1.3),
  y = c(-0.5, 0, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 2.1, 1.7, 1, 1.5,
  2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 2.1, 3.2, 2.8, 2.1, 2.2, 3.3, 3.2)
)

# Currently we need to manually merge the two together
datapoly <- merge(values, positions, by=c("id"))

(p <- ggplot(datapoly, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_polygon(aes(fill=value, group=id)) + 
  geom_path(color="white"))
dev.copy(svg, "Polygon.svg")
dev.off()
```

This produces a svg file nicely with one slight drawback: the "borders" increase when the size of the picture is increased (as expected). From what I can see here ([Constant border in a dynamic SVG graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839936/constant-border-in-a-dynamic-svg-graphic)), this is normal behaviour for svg files. The issue is that I interpret these paths as "boundaries" or "borders" rather than areas, so they 'should' have constant width at every zoom level.

What is the best way to produce a picture from R that allows for svg-like scalability on the interior of polygons but respects the zero-dimensional width of paths/borders/boundaries?

The context of this question is producing maps based on the Australian electoral divisions. (See [Mapping Australian electoral divisions with ggplot2](http://stronginstruments.com/2013/08/18/mapping-australian-electoral-divisions-with-ggplot2/).) Apart from subsetting as the author suggests, I'd like to produce a file that could be zoomed in on the smaller divisions (around Sydney for example). Suggestions for completely new ways of doing this are welcome, although I do prefer solutions that are compatible with `ggplot2`.

Comment: It looks like [some implementations of SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#NonScalingStroke) allow a non-scaling-stroke, but whether this works for displaying the image will be hugely dependent on the viewing/rendering program, i.e. Firefox, Inkscape may all have different interpretations. Does setting a tiny line width (e.g - 0.001) work?

Comment: Tiny line widths do help on high zoom, but (of course) the boundaries are less or not visible at low zoom. That link looks promising, but of course implementing it in R might be another thing.

Comment: Have you tried saving the ggplot as a pdf then using Inkscape? I find that this allows you to get a much crisper output than the png output by R.